# How do I move the char value of an integer in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to move a char from array to a different array. My problem is that I'm transfering the int value, and not the character.

This is what i see in my debugging.

BX points to the start of the array that i want put the char into: `MOV BX,[BP+8]`

The function's title is: `void encode(char code_array[], char msg[], char encoded_msg[]);`

[image]

Comment: You really _are_ copying bytes (which can also be viewer as ASCII characters) in this loop (the part that we can see). -- In general it's better to paste the code in here as text.

Comment: the rest of the code is kinda irrelevant since i already got the char i want in CL, i just dont know how to transfer the letter.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "transfer the letter".  Please create a [mcve], explain what happens when you run it, and what you want to have happen instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge I explained that i need to move 'L' into [BX], The problem is it moves the int value of that letter. I dont want to expand too much because it involves a C code and i will have to explain the whole question.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to move the character 'L' and instead you're moving the number 76?  They are exactly the same thing!  If somewhere else in your code you are expecting to see the letter `L` and instead you see the number 76, then the problem is with how you are doing the output.

Comment: @NateEldredge so it was working this whole time lol. i thought there is a problem because the dosbox crashes after doing the popping and ret at the end.

Comment: That's a separate issue :) To exit a program in DOS, you don't ret from it, you issue int21h function 4C.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.  Copy/paste text into a code block.  Also, CL is the low byte of CX; this doesn't make much sense if it's part of a loop.